# Using N64 controller as a USB mouse on a Mac

Tags: mac, usb, mouse, game-controller

Is it possible to connect the wires from an N64 controller to a USB port and use it as a mouse? Could I use a program to customize what the buttons do?

I'm okay with having to get more hardware to make it work, as I assume there is some free space in the controller. I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try [Amazon.com: Nintendo 64 N64/Playstation 2 PS2-PC USB Adapter Cable!: Video Games](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0009VJ376). It appears to work flawlessly under Leopard / Snow Leopard.